# Outlook 2010 keeps copying me when I reply

Tags: microsoft-outlook-2010

When I `reply all` to emails in Outlook 2010, I am getting copied, meaning I get a copy of the email in both my inbox and sent items. This has happened all of a sudden, with no reason that I'm aware of. I do not make any changes to my settings in Outlook, I always use it as is.

I'm using Exchange for this account, and I only have 1 email account in Outlook.

Going to Files -> Options -> Mail, under Replies and forwards, the option `When replying to a message that is not in the inbox, save the reply in the same folder` is not checked.

I have attempted a repair.

How do I fix this issue?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since there are a few posts on the internet describing very similar/same issue, and because it's such an odd bug, I thought I'd put this solution up for others.

The odd solution is to go to `Control Panel`, `Programs and Features` and find `Micosoft Office 2010`. Click `change`, then choose `Add or Remove Features`.

Click Continue.

Change nothing, just simply click Continue

Whilst I would have though a repair would do the same, they clearly do something different as this fixes the issue.